# append value to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If one want to append to this type of array:

```
array = ["one","two","three"];
```

so it becomes,

```
array = ["one","two","three, "four"];
```

use:

```
array.push("four");
```

but how do you append here:

```
object = {element1: one, element2: two, array: ["one","two","three"]};
```

so it becomes,

```
object = {element1: one, element2: two, array: ["one","two","three,"four"]};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You still use `push()`, but on the `array` property of your object:

```js
var obj = {
  element1: 1,
  element2: 2,
  array: ["one", "two", "three"]
};

obj.array.push('four');

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: supposing instead of var obj we have jQuery.obj ?

Comment: What do you mean by `jQuery.obj`?

Comment: jQuery.obj = { element1: 1, ... }

Comment: Then use `jQuery.obj.array.push('four');` However you really, *really* should not be polluting the jQuery namespace with your own variables.

Comment: I did. I then get error: Reference Error: Cant find variable array

Comment: Then you haven't defined the array correctly. As I said though, the problem is moot as you should not store the variable there anyway

Answer (score 3):

You can update an object in place like so:

```
let obj = {element1: 'one', element2: 'two', array: ["one","two","three"]};
obj.array.push('four');
```

If you want to create a new copy of the object with the extended array, you can also do the following using the new ES6 features:

```
let obj = {element1: 'one', element2: 'two', array: ["one","two","three"]};
let newObject = Object.assign({}, obj, { array: [...obj.array, 'four'] });
```

Using the second example, you keep the original object intact and create a new copy with the updated values.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the values `one, two` have to be strings, otherwise they will be treated as variables, and you can use `push` too for the object using `object.array.push('four');`:

```js
var object = {
  element1: "one",
  element2: "two",
  array: ["one", "two", "three"]
};
object.array.push('four');
console.log(object);
```